# Allow Adwords Query ?gclid=* in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-ads-api

My adwords session are not being tracked because my htaccess is rewriting query strings to the original urls for example

example.co.uk/product.html?gclid=123 is redirect back to example.co.uk/product.html

### workaround for HTTP authorization

### in CGI environment

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

#

### TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

is there anyway in Htaccess i can allow ?gclid=* to not redirect

thanks
Mike

Comment: Yes, but add your htaccess code in your question (edit)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, i have no code as i dont know how to do it. if you show me an example that might work i could try it?

Comment: In your question "My htaccess is rewriting query strings" ??? And I tell you how to fix it...

Comment: Arrr sorry, thats an assumption because everytime i try a query on  a product it redirect so im assuming that my htaccess or server must be doing it? Is there away i can say dont redirect queries containing gclid

Comment: From me, not without your htaccess or config. I do not know what the problem is, I can not solve it.

Comment: ############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################

Comment: Could that cause the problem?

Comment: it redirects everything to index.php... But it is certainly another rule (because product.html does not change).

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/?$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Yes. Add your code in the question [edit]

Comment: Added it to the first question

Comment: No, it's not that, because it's a redirect with www. you don't use that in the beginning of your question...

Comment: Added 2 more bits. thank you for helping